# Can a home be designed to specifically "retain heat"?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

Assume you have two identical bodies at temperature $T$.  One is subject to an environment characterized by a temperature of $T+\Delta T$.  The other is subject to an environment subject to a temperature of $T-\Delta T$.

Let $\dot Q_{1,2}$ be the rate at which heat flows from the object to the environment in two cases.

What mechanism, if any, would the rate of heat exchange in the first case not be the same magnitude, i.e. $\dot Q_{1} \neq -\dot Q_2$?

Suppose that in addition to the general ambient temperature of $T \pm \Delta T$, there is a separate stream of black body radiation with temperature $T_s >> T+\Delta T$ illuminating the objects under both conditions.  Let $C$ represent the rate of heat flow from the object when the local ambient temperature is $T$.  With this addition, is there a way for the magnitude of the rate of heat transfer to the local environment to differ?  I.e. $\dot Q'_1 + \dot Q'_2 \neq 2 C$?

Comment: All kinds of design features can be used, from using siting and vegetation, wall thickness and materials, specific window directions and eaves tailored to maximize sun in winter and shade in summer. Not really a physics problem.

Comment: @JonCuster how do "wall thickness and materials" create an asymmetric temperature response?

Comment: One tailors them so the interior response to the 24 hour cycle external temperature variation matches what you need in a particular place. Cliff dwellings shaded in summer, but want it warmer inside on winter nights, so walls are made to be diffusing in heat collected during the day to warm the inside.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_solar_building_design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to keep a house warm (from a warmer day into the night or from human activities that generate heat) is to increase thermal insulation. Nature requires the thermal conduction of passive materials to be symmetric. However, the material property of thermal conductivity depends on temperature and thus can be asymmetric for temperature excursions above and below the nominal house temperature.

One can also increase the heat capacity of a house to buffer temperature swings (such as nightly cold conditions). Unfavorably, this would tend to prolong heat-wave effects inside. The heat capacity is also temperature dependent, also potentially leading to notable asymmetry. For example, the heat capacity of water during freezing (or any material in a first-order phase transition) is infinite; [freezing and accumulating layers of slush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_pond) during winter can provide cooling during the summer. Conversely, the opposite strategy (storing warm water for the winter) is not effective because the [sensible heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_heat) is much smaller than the [latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat).

An asymmetric way to keep a house warm is to absorb as much sunlight as possible in the visible-wavelength range and reradiate as little as possible in the infrared range (e.g., from southern-facing windows in the Northern Hemisphere, to obtain a greenhouse effect). The analytical framework here is that the radiative emissivity $\varepsilon(\lambda)$ and transmissivity $\tau(\lambda)$ depend on the wavelength $\lambda$; bodies of different temperatures radiate different wavelengths, and transparent materials transmit different wavelengths with different efficiency.)

Another asymmetric mechanism relies on apertures such as windows that can be opened and closed as desired (or turned into insulators, as described in the comments), depending on whether one desires convective transfer with the outside. (You've since edited your question to exclude this mechanism.)

Comment: So the TLDR is just "large south facing windows that catch the sun"  (present for warmth during winter; absent for cooler during the summer.)?  possibly modulated by things like eaves or vegitation

Comment: @Dave - a friend of mine rented a house up in the mountains one year. The windows, all south facing, were actually two windows panes separated by 6" of empty space. Well, except when you pushed a button on the wall, and the space filled up with Styrofoam beads. So, sun in during the day (on to a black rock wall), minimal heat loss at night.

Comment: @JonCuster Sounds expensive. But maybe worth it in the middle of nowhere. Was there like a pump to remove the beads or something?

Comment: @DKNguyen - indeed, some kind of a fan. Fun to watch them come fountaining up from the bottom of the window, then get sucked back down out of sight the next day.

Comment: @JonCuster Oh they were blown up into position? I had imagined they were dropped down into position.

Comment: @DKNguyen - nope, storage was down. Probably harder to vacuum them upwards than suck them down. Always had a few sticking to the window though it seemed - lots of static attraction for little Styrofoam beads.